# RestSharp, returning IRestRequest content as something usable

Tags: c#, restsharp

This is a bit of a noobie question in the RestSharp department (and the C# department for that matter), so if that rubs you the wrong way, please take no offence.

I've recently started using RestSharp in my C# application, and I've gotten it to return the content I'd like through an IRestRequest.

The problem is that it returns this content can only be obtained as `char`.

That might be a little vague, so here's my code:

```
IRestRequest applicationReq = new RestRequest("somewhere/something", Method.GET);
IRestResponse applicationResp = client.Execute(applicationReq);
```

I want to actually use the `applicationResp.Content` that is returned, but it seems to return this result as `char`.

Is there any way I can convert this to something more usable? Like, for example a `Dictionary`?

Thus far, the only way I've even found to 'extract' this data from the `applicationResp.Content` is by dumping it to a list, as follows:

```
List<char> ar = new List<char>();
ar = applicationResp.Content.ToList();
```

All that gives me though is  along list of `char`s.

Can anyone recommend me a neat way of putting the content into a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone recommend me a neat way of putting the content into a
>   Dictionary

If you know the return type of your REST call is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you can use the generic version which accepts a type `T` of the desired return type:

```
IRestRequest applicationReq = new RestRequest("somewhere/something", Method.GET);
IRestResponse applicationResp = client.Execute<Dictionary<string, string>>(applicationReq);

Dictionary<string, string> returnedData = applicationResp.Data;
```

Comment: Maybe you've written wrong, or maybe I'm not getting it, but `IRestResponse applicationResp = client.Execute < Dictionary<string, string>(applicationReq);` just tells me that `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`.

Comment: @ViRALiC You're right, i forgot the closing `>` in the dictionary declaration. Fixed.